# NSStatusItem draw animation when highlighted

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, nsview, nsstatusitem

I'm using NSStatusItem in my project and I want it animated when my program is running. It is works fine when item is not selected. But when i'm clicking on it the image is freezing. I was trying to set alternate image by timer but no result. The latest idea was to draw NSView over my NSStatusItem but no result as well.

```
- (void)startAnimating
{
    currentFrame = 1;
    animTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/15.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopAnimating
{
    [animTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)updateImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    if (currentFrame == 13)
    {
        currentFrame = 1;
    }
    NSImage* image;
    if ([window backingScaleFactor] == 1.0)
    {
        image = [NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"App_18_gr_%d",currentFrame]];
        NSRect rect = [[StatusItem view] frame];
        [image drawInRect:[[StatusItem view] frame] fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
        [image setTemplate:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        image = [NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"App_36_gr_%d",currentFrame]];
        [image drawInRect:[[StatusItem view] frame] fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
        [image setTemplate:YES];
    }
    [StatusItem setImage:image];
    currentFrame++;
}
```